# How to Display a mesaage if I tried to save duplicate data into database in mvc4 .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a mvc4 project in .net framework.I have a html page which has some text boxes for input and below that four button is there like save, update, delete, show. All are working very well.

Now now I want to put some validation in this project

1. if I tried to save data which is already there(primary key is enable in database) a message should be display that "data is already present" and that data should be show.
2. in the date column.date should not exceed by the system date and not less than the 3 days before date.

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. Show what you have so far and explain, in detail, how you are stuck.

Comment: 1) Before saving the record, check if it exists.  Respond to that condition however you like.  2) Use validation tools in the framework, or simply check the value when receiving the record in the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. create action Method in controller which takes data and check in
   database      for dublicate e.g. **IsRecordExist(parameters)**
2. if data exist in database this function should return true else
   return false
3. create jquery function **checkDublicate()** this function should return 
   true or false
4. Inside that function use **ajax()** function to pass data to function in
   controller it return true then record exist if false    then record
   is not in database
5. Now on form submit call **checkDublicate()** function if it return true data exist and show errors using **validationEngine()**.